# i want value from input field which is using template drive form of angular and giving me previously typed value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10

Below is my .html file

```
<div class="p-field p-grid">
            <label for="username" class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 100px;">Username</label>
            <div class="p-col">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                id="username" 
                name="username"
                ngModel
                required
                pInputText
                #username="ngModel"
                (keypress)="enterkeypress($event)"
                >
                <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!username.valid && username.touched">Please enter an username!</span>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Below is my .ts file (showing only enterkeypress function)

```
enterkeypress(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }
```

**Output**

When i Entered the word **R** its showing me **Empty output**
[image]

When i Entered the second word **T** its showing me previous output **R**
[image]

And So ON, its always giving me previous value instead of current value
[image]

Please Help!!!!!!!! Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event  You may want to use the `input` event instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this. I couldn't get your statement. How i will user input evet. Please give code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event